# AngularJS $http not returning entire Select Statment

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

So I keep getting the first entry from this table but there are three in there (I swear).  The alert response for success and the page its going to only return the first so I know it is not returning three of anything.  Here is my Javascript.

```
var itemSeletor = angular.module('itemIndex', []);
itemSeletor.controller('EventController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("itemIndexAjax.php")
  .then(
     function(response) {
        // Success
          $scope.events = [response.data];
          //alert(response.data.events[0].name);
     },
     function(response){
        // Error
        alert("Error!");
        console.error(response);
     }
  );
});
```

And here is my php script:

```
.....
$event_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title, image, id FROM events");
if(!$event_stmt)
{
   $sqlString = sprintf("SQL Query Prep Failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
   echo json_encode(array("success" => false,
                                  "message" => $sqlString));
   exit;
}
$event_stmt->execute();
$event_stmt->bind_result($title, $image, $id);

$events = array();

while($event_stmt->fetch())
{
            $this_event = array("name" => $title, "pic" => $image, "id" 
                          => $id);
            array_push($events, $this_event);
}
$event_stmt->close();
echo json_encode(array("events" => $events));
exit;
?>
```

Could be the ng-repeat.

```
  <span id="imageAndText" ng-repeat="event in events | filter:query">
    <a href="event.php?id=" + "{{event.id}}">
       <img src="{{event.pic}}" id="image" alt="Image Not Found">
       <span class=eventTitle">
          {{event.name}}
       </span>
    </a>    
  </span>
```

Comment: just assign `$scope.events = response.data.events`

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  Such a small mistake

Answer (score 0):

ng-src it will help you

`enter code here`
          {{event.name}}

Comment: Thanks, that also helped